# How to set a predefined SortDescriptionCollection in xaml to CollectionViewSource

Tags: wpf, xaml, collectionviewsource

I have a SortDescriptions defined in xaml like this :-

```
<scm:SortDescriptionCollection x:Key="sortDescriptors">
    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Description" />
    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Id" />
</scm:SortDescriptionCollection>
```

How can I reference this in CollectionViewSource :-

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="csv" Source="{Binding DataContext}" >
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
         <!- how to reference it here ->
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

I have multiple CollectionViewSource, and I want to share sortDescriptors among them.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="csv" Source="{Binding DataContext}" >
<CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
  <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Description"/>
  <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Id"/>
</CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>      
</CollectionViewSource>
```